# How to subtract the node getChangedTime from 1 year

Tags: forms

I created a field that display a nodes last changed date using hook_form alter like this.

```
function demo3_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
   $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
   $form['field_message'] = array(
     '#type' => 'item',
     '#title' => t('Changed date'),
     '#markup' => format_date($node->getChangedTime(), 'medium'),
   );
}
```

I need to create a new field underneath it for the Review date. This field needs to subtract the getChangedTime from a period of 1 year or 365 days. So if the changed date was 30 days ago. The Review date will be 335 days and display in a medium format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Going under the assumption that this is Drupal 8 (based on the `$node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();` line, you can do something like this:

```
function demo3_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'node_page_edit_form') {
    /** @var \Drupal\Core\Datetime\DateFormatterInterface $date_formatter */
    $date_formatter = \Drupal::service('date.formatter');

    $node = $form_state->getFormObject()->getEntity();
    $changed = $node->getChangedTime();
    $review = new \DateTime();
    $review->setTimestamp($changed);
    $review->modify('+1 year');

    $form['field_message'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t('Changed date'),
      '#plain_text' => $date_formatter->format($changed, 'medium'),
    );

    $form['field_review'] = array(
      '#type' => 'item',
      '#title' => t('Review date'),
      '#plain_text' => $date_formatter->format($review->getTimestamp(), 'medium'),
    );
  }
}
```

Your other option is to use the timeago methods on DateFormatterInterface.

Comment: Thank you mpdonadio. And Yes its Drupal 8. I tried this but i get an error when clearing cache and I get a WSOD? It might just be a missing bracket.

Comment: This is the line that causing the error: $review->modify('+1 year);

Comment: okay i added a missing quote to 1 year I dont have an clear cache error now but I still have a WSOD :$review-> modify('+1 year');

Comment: Try $review->add(new \DateInterval('P1Y'));

Comment: @paulcap1 That's what I get for going from memory (I got some classes mixed up in my head).  The edit should work now; I actually tested it.  The method Jaypan works, too (I never can remember the DateInterval syntax).

Comment: Works perfect! Thank you.I see the change to $review. Is it possible to create a custom field and widget that is programmed to do these functions. A real cck field so that a site Admin could and add this custom field "changedate" and "reviewdate" to any content type they wanted to?